# OwnershipTransfer not working. 403 ERROR consentRequiredForOwnershipTransfer - Consent is required to transfer ownership of a file to another user

Tags: api, drive

Google drive api V3 file/folder ownership transfer does not seem to work.
I am trying to transfer folder ownership from a normal google (non organization) account to another normal google account.

Is there a bug or 'm I missing something here.

Please see snapshot attached. Below is the error message.403 ERROR consentRequiredForOwnershipTransfer - Consent is required to transfer ownership of a file to another user.

What Consent can I set up? this is my personal account and I granted full access on consent screen prompt.

[Google Developer method test snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUEfD.jpg)

Many thanks for your advise.

Comment: hoping someone can shed some light, thanks!